# .then is not a function?? inquirer node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirerjs

I have a basic function im trying to run with node js and inquirer, and when i run it console log gives me this error. TypeError: inquirer.createPromptModule(...).then is not a function. I have seen a similar answer asked and the problem was there version of inquirer was old im running version 8.2.4 and im having the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const fs = require("fs");
const generateMarkdown = require ("./util/generateMarkdown.js");


const questions = [
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "What is your Github username?",
        name: "Username",
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "What is your Email adress?",
        name: "email" 
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "What is your projects name?",
        name: "project",
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "Description of your project:",
        name: "description",
    },
    {
        type: "checkbox",
        message: "What license does your project require? (SPACEBAR to checkmark and ENTER to confirm)",
        name: "license",
        choices: ['MIT', 'APACHE 2.0', 'GPL 3.0', 'BSD 3', 'N/A'],
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "What command should run dependencies?",
        name: "install",
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "what command should be used to run tests?",
        name: "test",
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "What does the user need to know about this repo?",
        name: "use",
    },
    {
        type: "input",
        message: "How does the user contribute to this repo?",
        name: "contribute",
    },
];


function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
    FontFaceSet.writeToFile(fileName, data, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("File Created");
    })
}


function init() {
    inquirer.createPromptModule(questions).then((data) => {
        const readmeFile = generateMarkdown(data);
        writeToFile("generatedReadMe.md",readmeFile);
    })
}


init();
```

Comment: According to the documentation this should work, but the latest version starts with a 9, not 8!

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, i figured out what i did wrong VSC auto completed createPromptModule when all i wanted to put there was prompt.

Comment: According to the documentation `createPromptModule()` does not return a `Promise` but a prompt function. That prompt function is what returns the promise: `let prompt = inquirer.createPromptModule(); prompt(questions).then(...`

Answer (score -1):

Fixed after 45 mins of staring at the code i realized VSC auto completed and added CreatePromptModule when i was just trying to add prompt.

Comment: try adding some example code in questions and solutions also.